# Stripe Android - Set Locale For Error Messages

Tags: android, stripe-payments, locale, stripes

Is there way to display all the error from stripe in french?.
Currently, all the error response from stripe is displayed in English.
Even after changing device language, the error still display in English only.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_STRIPE) {
            WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);
            // Handle the result of stripe.confirmSetupIntent
            stripe.onSetupResult(requestCode, data, new ApiResultCallback<SetupIntentResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull SetupIntentResult result) {
                    SetupIntent setupIntent = result.getIntent();
                    SetupIntent.Status status = setupIntent.getStatus();
                    if (status == SetupIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                        // Setup completed successfully
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            if (weakActivity.get() != null) {
                                // show success popup
                            
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (status == SetupIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                        // Setup failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
                            if (activity != null) {
                                Log.e("error --> ",setupIntent.getLastSetupError().getMessage()); // display text based on locale
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // Setup request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
                        if (activity != null) {
                            Log.e("error --> ",e.getMessage()); // display text based on locale
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe setting the phone's locale should just work here. What exact language/locale do you use on the phone?

Comment: My device language is french.

Comment: Strange, it should just work! The message returned in the exception should be localised if you're using a recent version of the stripe-android library. Could you try again? Might have been a blip.